# What is the correct way of passing a Mongoose object into the MongoDB underlying connection insert() method

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I need to insert many thousands of documents into MongoDB. I want to use Mongoose for its casting properties, etc. However I cannot figure out how to pass the generated instances to the MongoDB connection. I have tried this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./config.json"));

mongoose.connect(config.mongoDBUrl);
db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', function () {

    var TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        testStr : String
    });

    var Model = mongoose.model('test_schema_2', TestSchema);

    var inst = new Model();
    inst.testStr = "EWAFWEFAW";

    // This works.
    db.collection('test_schema_2').insert({ testStr : 'My Test Str'}, {}, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Written.');
            db.close();
        }
    });

    // This doesn't.
    db.collection('test_schema_2').insert(inst, {}, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Written.');
            db.close();
        }
    });
});
```

In the second case, I get: "[RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]"

What is Mongoose breaking behind the scenes that stops this from working, and how can I make it work?

Comment: You need to use the methods off of the model if you want the schema validation and casting. Right now you are just grabbing a handle to the underlying node driver for your actual insert operations, which also do not do this theselves. Mongoose validation only works on the `.save()` method invocation so just throwing to a document instance is not helping you even with a `.toObject()` call which you are missing and also getting into trouble with.

Comment: So, do Mongoose plan to give us a bulk insert in the future so their library is at least vaguely useful? Sorry, this subject is starting to infuriate me.

Comment: Possibly, but really you have been told twice now that **you** are doing it wrong. If you are just trying to use the plain collection methods then you should be just be using plain objects, or otherwise jumping back through hoops to convert again back to plain objects. I have already stated that you are not getting the benefits you think you are getting from casting as Mongoose documents. So the simple answer is not not cast. Just take your data and feed in to the insert method or even the bulk API methods.

Comment: Understood. I will do this then, create the objects using the node.js mongodb driver, make sure all the data types are correct manually, then insert the raw objects. This is the only way I'm going to get it done, right?

Comment: You need raw objects is the point. Mongoose documents have a lot more in them than just the fields.

Answer (score 0):

To save an instance of a model you just have to do

```
inst.save(function(err) {
    //Do something here
});
```

Comment: No, I need to use insert() because eventually I want to pass an array of thousands of them, and i want the write to happen as fast as possible. Mongoose doesnt support proper bulk inserts.